# Какой размер холста должен быть?

Tags: веб-дизайн, figma

Хочу нарисовать макет сайта, но у меня вопрос, какой размер холста я должен указывать? Вот экран у меня 1366

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите нарисовать макет сайта, то размер холста должен соответствовать размеру экрана, на котором будет отображаться сайт. Если ваш экран имеет разрешение 1366 х 768 пикселей, то размер холста для макета можно сделать таким же, то есть 1366 пикселей в ширину и 768 пикселей в высоту.

Однако стоит учесть, что не все пользователи будут иметь экраны с таким же разрешением. Поэтому, чтобы сайт был адаптивным и выглядел правильно на разных экранах, рекомендуется создавать макеты для нескольких размеров экранов. Обычно, макеты создаются для трех основных типов экранов: десктоп (на пример 1920 x 1080), планшет (на пример 1024 x 768) и смартфон (на пример 375 x 667).

Comment: угу, понял, спасибо. Тогда просто создавать холст 1920 сразу и все :)